# What is the translation of "whom I uphold" In Hebrew which it were montioned in Isaiah?

Tags: jesus, translation-philosophy, isaiah, bible-versions

In Isaiah 42:1-4  there is an attractive testament which is :

“Behold! My Servant, **whom I uphold**; My Elect One, in whom My soul delights! I have put My Spirit upon Him; He will bring forth justice to the Gentiles. 2 He shall not cry out, nor raise His voice, nor cause His voice to be heard in the street. 3 A bruised reed shall He not break, and smoking flax shall He not quench. In truth He shall bring forth justice. 4 He shall not fail nor be discouraged, till He has established justice in the earth; and the islands shall wait for His law.”

— Isaiah 42:1-4

**Now my question here is**  What is the translation of "whom I uphold" In Hebrew which it were montioned in Isaiah ?

Comment: [Link](http://www.studybible.info/strongs/H8551).

Comment: @Lucian, Are you affraid to say that is means " Ahmed" which means Mohamed peace be upon him, The OP asked about translation not to give him link

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: The link contains a wealth of information, along with a plethora of possible translations and interpretations. Also, the Arabic [aHMaD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-M-D) and Hebrew aTMaK appear unrelated.

Comment: You create a question and one of your fellow Muslims posts the answer. You really think the members of this site don't know what you are doing? Your attempts at Muslim proselytization are futile.

Comment: @DerÜbermensch, The same trick were made by christians , Christian upvote and accept only question of Christians even they wrong , be fair , you should have convincing arguments , you are jalouse from Muhamed , Muhamed peace be upon him is the right and messenger of all world , you can't delete this truth from right and you can't cover sun by sieve

Comment: Thanks for your help, here, @Lucian.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Question: What is the translation of "whom I uphold" In Hebrew which it were montioned in Isaiah?**

The Answer is :**Ahmed**

"Here is my servant, whom I support (אתמך = atmak), my chosen one, in whom my soul delights; I have put my Spirit upon him; he will bring forth justice to the nations."

This word אתמך is used once in the bible.The Hebrew term corresponding to the phrase "support/uphold" is the root tamak and it appears totally 21 times in the Old Testament, mostly under the form: tāmaḵtā, tāməḵā, təmaḵtîḵā, tāməḵū, tāmōḵ, tiṯmōḵ ...but only once takes a weird form ei. "atmak".

Funny enough it seems that אתמך(atmak) is very similar in writing to אחמד(Ahmed).  Not to mention אתמך (Atmc) happens to be a special term foretelling the coming of a righteous man and is used only ONCE throughout the entire Book. It seems that there was an error regarding the first letter. One letter is all it takes to change the truth.

The past scribes have accidentally or deliberately made a grave mistake.

Isaiah 42

"Here is my servant, Ahmed, my chosen one, in whom my soul delights; I have put my Spirit upon him; he will bring forth justice to the nations. He will not shout or cry out or raise his voice in the streets. A bruised reed he will not break, and a smoldering wick he will not snuff out. In faithfulness he will bring forth justice; he will not falter or be discouraged till he establishes justice on earth. In his teaching the islands will put their hope.” This is what God the Lord says—the Creator of the heavens, who stretches them out, who spreads out the earth with all that springs from it, who gives breath to its people, and life to those who walk on it: “I, the Lord, have called you in righteousness; I will take hold of your hand. I will keep you and will make you to be a covenant for the people and a light for the Gentiles, to open eyes that are blind, to free captives from prison and to release from the dungeon those who sit in darkness. “I am the Lord; that is my name! I will not yield my glory to another or my praise to idols. See, the former things have taken place, and new things I declare; before they spring into being I announce them to you.” Sing to the Lord a new song, his praise from the ends of the earth, you who go down to the sea, and all that is in it, you islands, and all who live in them. Let the wilderness and its towns raise their voices; let the settlements where Kedar lives rejoice. Let the people of Sela sing for joy; let them shout from the mountaintops."

Kedar(son of Ishmael) = Arabs Sela = mountain in Medina He will be an Arab, preaching in Medina, singing a new song aka reciting the Quran, He will be a light to the gentiles, meaning he is not only sent to the children of Israel.

Comment: @Downvoter , The Answer was from your Bible

Comment: If a transmission error occurred, it seems to have happened at least a millennium before Mohamed, since the [Greek Septuagint](http://www.greekdoc.com/polyglot/isa42.html#v1) reads the [same](http://www.greekdoc.com/lexicon/antil.html#antilambanw) as the Hebrew Masoretic Text.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik, Thanks for your answer , that is the fact , the Translation is Ahmed , I have got it [here](http://mustafa-apologist.blogspot.com/2017/11/isaiah-421-ahmed.html) you will find this expression which show the jalouse of jew and charistian against Muhamed peace be upon him אחמד Ahmed in Hebrew

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: Hebrew is related to Arabic, and the Hebrew equivalent of Arabic HMD words are also HMD words (as opposed to TMK words). If you want or choose to believe that an original HMD root has, in the course of time, ultimately become corrupted into a TMK root, then that is certainly your prerogative.

Comment: This answer is quite unbiblical - Ahmed is unrelated to the Hebrew  אֶתְמָךְ־ (’eṯ·māḵ-).

Answer (score 0):

The text of Isa 42:1 is, Here is my servant, whom I uphold, my chosen one in whom I delight; I will put my Spirit on him, and he will bring justice to the nations.

The person speaking is YHWH (V5) about the chosen servant.  This is one of the four famous "servant songs" in Isaiah, all of which are wonderful prophecies of the coming Messiah. The most famous servant song is Isa 53 about the suffering servant.

The operative word in Isa 42:1, translated "whom I uphold" is אֶתְמָךְ־ (’eṯ·māḵ-) is a verb, Qal - Imperfect - first person common singular, from the lexical root,  תָּמַך (tamak) which means (in this instance):

> 2 hold up, support, with בְּיָדָיו Exodus 17:2 (E); figurative, ב
>   person Isaiah 42:1; Psalm 41:13; Psalm 63:9; accusative of person
>   Isaiah 41:10 (ב instrumental), Proverbs 29:23 (opposed to הִשְׁמִּיל),
>   [Brown-Driver-Briggs]

The structure of the first half of Isa 1:1 consists of two verb-phrases in apposition describing the the suffering servant:

- the one I uphold, and,
- the chosen one in whom I delight.

Ellicott observes this:

> Behold my servant . . .--Here the words point not, as before, to the
>   visible, or even the ideal Israel, but to One who is the centre of
>   both, with attributes which are reproduced in His people in the
>   measure of their fulfilment of the ideal. "Elect" is another of the
>   words with which Isaiah has fashioned the theology of Christendom. It
>   meets us there four times (45:4, 65:9, 22), and is echoed and
>   interpreted in the voice from heaven of Matthew 3:17. That voice fixed
>   on the human consciousness of the Son of Man that He was "the servant
>   of the Lord," and throughout His life we trace an ever expanding and
>   conscious reproduction of the chief features of Isaiah's picture.
>   Disciples like St. Matthew learnt to recognise that likeness even in
>   what might seem to us subordinate details (Matthew 12:17-21).

The Pulpit Commentary reaches the same conclusion:

> ANNOUNCEMENT OF THE SERVANT OF THE LORD, AND THE WORK WHICH HE WILL
>   PERFORM. There are comparatively few who deny that, in this place at
>   any rate, the "Servant of the Lord" is the Messiah. (So the Targum on
>   the passage; so Abar-barnel; so, among moderns, Oehler, Delitzsch, and
>   Mr. Cheyne.) The portraiture has "so strong an individuality and such
>   marked personal features, that it cannot possibly be a mere
>   personified collective;" and it goes so "infinitely beyond anything of
>   which a man was ever capable that it can only be the future Christ"
>   (Delitzsch). It may be added that St. Matthew (Matthew 12:17-21)
>   distinctly applies the passage to our Lord. Verse 1. - Behold.
>   "Behold," as Mr. Cheyne says, "invites the attention of the world -
>   both of the Jews and of the nations - to a new revelation." It looks
>   back to the similar expression of vers. 24 and 29 of the preceding
>   chapter, which draw down the curtain upon the idol-gods, while this
>   "behold" reveals One who is to occupy their place, and to be a worthy
>   object of the worship of mankind, My Servant; i.e. my true and perfect
>   servant, utterly obedient (John 4:34; Hebrews 3:2); not, like Israel,
>   my rebellious and faithless servant; not, even, like my prophets,
>   yielding an imperfect obedience, Whom I uphold. "As the Father hath
>   life in himself, so hath he given to the Son to have life in himself"
>   (John 5:26). As the fount or origin of Divinity (πηγὴ Θεότητος), the
>   Father supports and sustains even the Son and the Spirit. Mine Elect
>   (comp. 1 Peter 2:6). Christ was "chosen" from all eternity in God's
>   counsels to the great work of man's redemption, and to be the Mediator
>   between God and man. I have put my Spirit upon him (see Isaiah 11:2;
>   Isaiah 61:1; and for the fulfilment, comp. Luke 2:40; Luke 3:22; Luke
>   4:18-21; Luke 3:34). He shall bring forth judgment to the Gentiles;
>   i.e. "he shall publish," or "cause to be published, to the Gentiles,
>   the true Law of God - religion on its practical side." The publication
>   of Christianity throughout all the world has abundantly fulfilled this
>   promise or prophecy. The call of the Gentiles had been already
>   declared by Isaiah in his earlier preaching (ch. 2:2; 11:10; 19:22-25;
>   25:6; 27:13, etc.).